# Too few arguments to function, 0 passed in and exactly 1 expected when using Mail

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to send a simple email using the Mailable class. I've followed this tutorial online to the tee and I'm still getting this error. I have no idea what the problem could be because everything seems fine and I've followed the tutorial step for step.
What am I doing wrong?

**TestMail.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class TestMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $details;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($details)
    {
        $this->details = $details;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Test Mail from Duke')->view('emails.TestMail');
    }
}
```

**MailController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Mail\TestMail;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class MailController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function sendEmail()
    {
        $details = [
            'title' => 'The Title',
            'body' => 'The body should be fine',
        ];
        Mail::to("sirduketylo@gmail.com")->send(new TestMail());
        return "Email Sent";
    }
}
```

**The route**

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\MailController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/send', [MailController::class, 'sendEmail']);
```

Comment: Which line did the error point to?   I do not see $details being passed.  It was created but not used.

Comment: In the TestMail.php, `public function __construct($details)
    {
        $this->details = $details;
    }` basically this whole function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TestMail` object expects a `$details` parameter passed in its constructor, yet none was supplied.

*(MailController)*

Instead of:❌

```php
 Mail::to("sirduketylo@gmail.com")->send(new TestMail());
```

Use this:✅

```php
 Mail::to("sirduketylo@gmail.com")->send(new TestMail($details));
```

##### Addendum

I suppose you intended to pass the `$details` to the View. Hence:

*(TestMail.php)*

```php
// ...

return $this
    ->subject('Test Mail from Duke')
    ->view('emails.TestMail')
    ->with("details", $this->details);

// ...
```

Comment: Gave you up an up vote because he understood you and not my comment.